# Eclipse CDT: How to find all the places that a variable is modified

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, variables, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible in Eclipse CDT to do a search on a variable name and only show results where a variable is modified or potentially modified? For example, the variable appears on the left-hand side of an assignment.

If not, is there some other utility that can parse code to produce this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the variable name, and choose "Open Call Hierarchy".

It can be picky; you might need to left-click it first to make it highlighted before right-clicking.

Comment: Thanks. Had no idea that "Call Hierarchy" might be related to variables!